# Veil LoadingImage or LoadingPanel over JFrame

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application, swingx

Is there any component in Swing(X) by which we can place a veil loading image over a panel or frame making it transparent during some lengthy background processing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few examples of Romain Guy's work:

Chapter 9 of [“Filthy Rich Clients” book](http://www.filthyrichclients.org/), with downloadable code

[SwingFX: Pretty Progress Panels](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19222.html)

[Glasspane Painting](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/GlasspanePainting.htm)

[GlassPane Intercepts](http://www.freecodesnippets.com/code/java/swing-components/glasspane/glasspane-intercepts-event)

And other example:

[GlassExample](http://maven.smith.edu/~jfrankli/220s04/jswing2/ch08/GlassExample.java)

Comment: Can you tell me where can I download SwingFX?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the Glass Pane, work through the [tutorial here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) and the relevant section [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a glasspane to the frame, thats right. But you also can use [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net)' JXFrame and simply set a waitpane and activate it when a loading action starts.
Have a look at the [API](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/swinglabs/swingx-core/1.6.2/swingx-core-1.6.2-javadoc.jar!/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXFrame.html)